# Prevent some class to override the Object class's method in java , confused about the answer

Tags: java, object

I find the question in some sites like "ow would you prevent someone from overriding the java.lang.Object class?" but none of the response I could understand. 
As per my thinking , it **may** be done -

> Can create a Base class and all the methods of Object class can be
>   overriden and then we can throw some unsupported exception for each
>   method , so further all subclasses won;t be able to access any of the
>   methods of Object or there is much more better way to do it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being too pedantic here, but there's no such thing as "overriding a class".  Methods are overridden, classes are not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a `FinalObject extends Object` class that overrides each of the Object methods and makes them `final`.

```
class FinalObject extends Object {
  public final int hashCode() { return super.hashCode(); }
  public final int equals(Object o) { return super.equals(o); }
  ...
}
```

Comment: How would this prevent someone from declaring `class myClass extends Object` and overriding methods in it?

Comment: There's absolutely no possible way to do that, under any circumstances.

Comment: That is, this is an answer to the only interpretation of the question that is answerable.

Answer (score 3):

Lookup the "final" modifier for classes and methods.

- [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2)